# GridView CAB not showing up on Long click

Tags: java, android, gridview, contextual-action-bar, onitemlongclicklistener

```
  gridView = (ExpandableGridview)findViewById(R.id.grid);

   gridView.setChoiceMode(ExpandableGridview.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ExpandableGridview.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {

            if(checked) {
                checkedItems.add(position);
            } else {
                checkedItems.remove(checkedItems.indexOf(position));
            }
            int checkedCount = gridView.getCheckedItemCount();
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " selected");

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            Log.i("test", "onCreateActionMode");
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            menu.findItem(R.id.done).setVisible(false);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.done).setVisible(true);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.done:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            checkedItems.removeAll(checkedItems);
        }
    });

gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            gridView.setItemChecked(position,!checkedItems.contains(position));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I am trying to pick multiple images to store in some other place. I tried with `GridView` and `ExpandableGridView` but `onCreateActionMode` never called.
its callback methods `onItemCLick` and `onItemLongClick` are also not working.

working fine if i am handling `onClick` through Adapter class.
Please help if i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` starts `ActionMode` by long clicking on one of it's items by default.
So, try to remove your custom `OnItemLongClickListener` and see, if that works.